# Program that gets x and y coordinates in a MATLAB GUI when clicked

Tags: matlab, mouseclick-event

I need a program that will run without all of the time without pausing to wait for a click.  The program should save the x and y coordinates of the click into a variable.

Comment: What have you done so far? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ButtonDownFcn of the axis, and then, in that function access and store the eventdata variable, wihch is a [1x2] double of the clicked coordinates.

It's hard to give you much of an answer with out more details...